# Toggle chromevox on OSX

Tags: macos, accessibility

What is the shortcut toggle chromevox on OSX?

For Windows it's `ctl+alt+z` but that doesn't seem to work on mac.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

FWIW, while Andrew's answer is technically correct, I feel like the OP was looking for the default answer.
It took me a few minutes to figure it out (during which I was getting ready to throw my computer out the window because it would not shut-up!).

On MacOS X (10.15.7 as of this writing), the default `ChromeVox` key is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>.

Then, the notation may not be obvious, but it's actually a 2 step sequence to toggle the reader on or off.
The documentation/mappings page says `ChromeVox+A>A`:

[image: ChromeVox mappings]

This means <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> , then release the 3 keys, then press <kbd>A</kbd> again

*notes*:
While it might have been a fluke, it appeared that my *ChromeVox modifier key* was empty when I first loaded the extension. I had to select the *Classic Keymap* and then hit *Reset current keymap* to populate.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. My Chromevox had the "Blank" modifier key on fresh install too. 

Unfortunately, toggling ChromeVox off is only temporary. as soon as there's any action in the browser, ChromeVox will turn itself back on. I'm using the plugin for Accessibility Testing, and work around was to disable the Extension via Chrome Extension list

Answer (score 1):

This varies, because ChromeVox...

- Uses different default modifier keys on each OS, and
- Has several default keymaps that a user can choose from, and
- Allows a user to override any keyboard mapping, including the ChromeVox modifier.

To find out which keyboard controls are used on your computer, open the ChromeVox options. You'll find these under...

- macOS Global Application Menu > Window > Extensions
- Find the ChromeVox extension, choose the "Details" button
- Choose the "Extension options" button, which opens the ChromeVox options in a new tab
- Check what the "ChromeVox modifier key" and "Toggle ChromeVox active or inactive" are set to.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone stumbling across this, ChromeVox wouldn't pick up my Shift+Alt+A>A key inputs, so in the settings I changed "ChromeVox modifier key" to "Ctrl" and "Toggle ChromeVox active or inactive" key to "Z".

To toggle active / inactive, you press and release Ctrl, then press and release Z.